# Generating and saving a list of ParseObjects within a Parse.Cloud.httpRequest in a cloud function

Tags: javascript, android, database, parse-platform

So, I'm defining a cloud function that's supposed to make a call to the foursquare api and generate a list of restaurants (each restaurant is a ParseObject) from the returned JSON. I successfully do this, but I run into problems when trying to save these objects to my database and send them back to my phone by calling response.success(). The large code block below saves the list to my database, but if I try

```
Parse.Object.saveAll(restaurants)
response.success(restaurants)
```

I end the function before all of the restaurants are saved. I tried using this line instead

```
Parse.Object.saveAll(restaurants).then(response.success(restaurants))
```

, but only half of the restaurants get saved before I get the error "Failed with: Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object." I also get this error if I call response.success(restaurants) without attempting to save the list. I read that this is a bug in parse preventing someone from printing or passing unsaved ParseObjects. Any ideas? I also tried using .then on the http request, but I get the same issues or a new error: "com.parse.ParseException: i/o failure: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out. "

```
Parse.Cloud.define("callFourSquare", function(request, response) {
//The Parse GeoPoint with current location for search
    var geo = request.params.location;
    var geoJson = geo.toJSON();
    var url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=" + geoJson.latitude + ","
        + geoJson.longitude +         "&section=food&sortByDistance=1&limit=50&venuePhotos=1&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&client_id=    C043AJBWKIPBAXOHLPA0T40SG5L0GGMQRWQCCIKTRRVLFPTH" 
        + "&client_secret=Y1GZZRHXEW1I3SQL3LTHQFNIZRDCTRG12FVIQI5QGUX0VIZP&v=20140715";
        console.log(url);
    //Call to FourSquare api, which returns list of restaurants and their details
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function (httpResponse) {
            var restaurants = [];
            var json = httpResponse.data;
            var venues = json.response.groups[0].items;
            console.log(venues.length)
            for(i = 0; i < venues.length; i++) {
                venue = venues[i].venue;

                var RestaurantObject =  Parse.Object.extend("Restaurant");
                var rest = new RestaurantObject();
                try {
                    rest.set("geoLocation", 
                    new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude: venue.location.lat, 
                        longitude: venue.location.lng}));

                } catch(err) {}
                try {
                    rest.set("address", venue.location.address + " " +     venue.location.formattedAddress[1]);
                } catch(err) {}
                try {
                    rest.set("phoneNumber", venue.contact.formattedPhone);
                } catch(err) {}
                try {
                    rest.set("website", venue.url);
                } catch(err) {}
                rest.set("name", venue.name);
                rest.set("lowerName", venue.name.toLowerCase());
                try {
                    rest.set("priceLevel", venue.price.tier);
                } catch(err) {}
                try {
                    rest.set("rating", venue.rating/2);
                } catch(err) {}
                try {
                    rest.set("storeId", venue.id);
                } catch(err) {}
                try {
                    rest.set("icon", venue.photos.groups[0].items[0].prefix + "original"
                        + venue.photos.groups[0].items[0].suffix)
                } catch(err) {}

                restaurants.push(rest);

            }
            Parse.Object.saveAll(restaurants);
        },
        error: function (httpResponse) {
            response.error("Request failed with response code:" + httpResponse.status + "     Message: "
                + httpResponse.text);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The error "Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object" is the key I think, are there any columns of type Pointer on your Restaurant class?

Comment: No, all of my columns are a mix of strings and numbers (e.g., restaurantName, phonenumber, website, rating etc.), along with one GeoPoint.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you aren't returning the Promise from Parse.Object.saveAll(restaurants) when your httpRequest() is complete.  Try returning that saveAll() promise and see if it completes.