# Create object on cloud code (Parse) with data from http request

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

Relatively new to Parse, but can't seem to find any help on this topic although it seems to be a basic thing to do.

In a cloud function, I am requesting JSON data from an API and want to turn this data into a PFObject so that I can access the data from an iOS app much quicker than just calling the data straight from the API. At the moment in my cloud function I have the following code which is happily retrieving the data. I have tried for a while now but not been able to create a Parse object from this JSON data. As an example I have put the facebook website API in.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateUniversities", function(request, response) {

       Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({,
       url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/alex.tsaptsinos',

       success: function(httpResponse) {        
           response.success(httpResponse.data)
        },
       error: function(httpResponse) {
           console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
           response.error(httpResponse.text);
        }
   });
});
```

I assume that I will have to create my object in the success part and then create and instance of it and manipulate it somehow, something along the lines of:

```
var NewObject =  Parse.Object.extend("Object");
var newObject = new NewObject();
//manipulation
```

Any help would be amazing, thanks a lot!

Comment: Your assumptions are all correct. What have you tried? Basically you make a bunch of calls to `newObject.set("field", value");` then call `newObject.save({ success: ... });` and trigger the `response.success()` in the callback.

Comment: You haven't done anything to create a new object. You have received the JSON data, and said that this was successful. Are you looking to create a new object in your iOS application or through the cloud code itself?

Comment: Looking to create it through the cloud code. Have tried something similar to Chris' approach, which I was from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835587/generating-and-saving-a-list-of-parseobjects-within-a-parse-cloud-httprequest-in question. However this didn't work and that question was never answered